# Could i install npm on cloud server?

Tags: node.js, laravel

Have cloud hosting on hetzner. Actually want to make laravel project. And i want to use laravel breeze and another packages and should install npm? I tried google it but i need your advice. please help me.

Comment: That's a question your hosting provider support should answer.

Comment: Hosting like this usually runs linux and you install npm packages on linux.  You should ask the hosting provider

Answer (score 0):

You can install all the packages on your local computer, then build your assets locally and ship the built assets to the server.

Whilst you can run npm run build on the server, you do not need to. You can do this locally then commit the built assets to your repository.